# Separate log from jboss server using log4j2

Tags: java, jboss, log4j2

I'm deploying my war in jboss EAP 7.2. I'm using log4j2 in my app and it's configured to write in a specific file, but instead jboss is writing the output on server.log. I have also the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file included :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure
xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Excluding logging JBoss modules -->
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.ext" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        <module name="org.slf4j.jcl-over-slf4j" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
        <module name="org.jboss.log4j.logmanager" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />

    </exclusions>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
</deployment>
```

This is the log configuration :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT"
            follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.telefonica.npro" level="debug"
            additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
    <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
    <RollingFile name="FileAppender"
        fileName="/home/nprouser/NPRO/batch/log/npro2020.log"
        filePattern="/home/nprouser/NPRO/batch/log/npro2020-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>
</Configuration>
```

The file is created but nothing is written there.

I'm not sure if I need to configure something on jboss.

Comment: Minor note you don't need the module exclusions if you're excluding the logging subsystem. Is your deployment a WAR or EAR? Also where is the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` located in your deployment?

Comment: it is a WAR and the xml is located on META-INF folder

Comment: You're not referencing the `FileAppender` in any logger definition.